# rails Getting the parameter from the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application that I want to add attachments to assets, so I want to be able to call http://localhost:3000/attachments/:asset_id/new so that that it will automatically bring in the asset id.  I don't know how to configure this in views, though I think I did it once-upon-a-time.  So how could I accomplish this task?

As far as I have got so far, and I believe this is correct is adding the following line to routes.rb:

```
 match 'attachments/:asset_id/new'=>'attachments#new'
```

**Note:** This is a Rails 3 Application.

Comment: Since I can't post the answer yet, I have posted the answer here: http://pessetto.com/question2answer/index.php?qa=30&qa_1=how-do-i-get-the-parameter-from-url-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the RESTful way like so:

```
resources :assets do
  resources :attachments # this would give you localhost:3000/assets/:asset_id/attachments/new for your #new action
end
```

or the non-RESTful way:

```
match 'attachments/:asset_id/new'=>'attachments#new', :as => "new_attachments_asset"
```

I'd recommend the former ;) For the restful example, your Attachment#new action could be:

```
def new
  @asset = Asset.find(params[:asset_id])
  @attachment = @asset.attachments.build # assuming a has_many/belongs_to association
end
```

Comment: I will do it the restful way once integrated into the actual system, I am assuming the new command needs to have: @attachment = Attachment.new(:asset_id => params[:asset_id]) in it to get the Asset_Id into the hidden field of the view.

Comment: This depends on the structure of your form. In the restful example using form helpers, you would usually have something like Attachment.new(params[:attachment]); your way you need to set every attribute yourself. Also keep in mind that your attributes need to be accessible for mass assignment (attr_accessible in your model) if you want to assign attribute values on Attachment.new

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. In the NEW action, you would have @asset = Asset.find(params[:asset_id]) && @asset.attachments.build (or in case of a has_one/belongs_to association: @asset.build_attachment)

Comment: Okay, I have designed it restfully, and my HTML output looks like this for the field I want assets in `<input id="attachment_asset_id" name="attachment[asset_id]" type="hidden" />`, but it appears `@attachment = Attachment.new(params[:attachment])` is not loading it in, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't remember the syntax fully at the moment, but I believe given my controller code above, you could do ´form_for [@asset, @attachment] ...´. Rails should take care of the asset_id then

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions